Add prefix phone number in MySQL trigger
I would like to be able to add the prefix +34 to the phone field just before it is inserted.
I have created the following trigger:
DELIMITER |
create trigger `prefix_phone` BEFORE INSERT ON `clientes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.telefono = CONCAT('+34');
END;
DELIMITER ;

But I get the following error:
"Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"
Thanks in advance!
Greetings!

CONCAT('+34')? Concat with what?

I would like to concatenate it with the phone number that is going to be inserted.
I couldn't think of any other way to try it.

I don't have a MySQL server here to verify the syntax error you're getting, but CONCAT('+34') is literally +34. You'll need to append the phone number, won't you?

I have tried to do the following: CONCAT('+34', NEW.phone); but I get the same error.
My idea is to simply add +34 in front of the phone before inserting it

I see 3 possible situations. 1) Entered value is already started with +34. No action needed in this case. 2) Entered value is started with 34. Only plus sign + must be added. 3) There is no needed prefix. +34 must be added.

I see to mistakes on the question.

The delimiter on the END
You have not included the new number to the CONCAT() function. Basically you are saying all new inserted number will be transformed to +34 (if the trigger will not failed with an error) .

Use
DELIMITER &&
 create trigger `prefix_phone` BEFORE INSERT ON `clientes`
  FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
    SET NEW.telefono = CONCAT('+34',NEW.telefono);
   END&&
DELIMITER ;

The following was tested on MariaDB, but in this case is identical in MySQL
MariaDB [asterisk]> create table clientes (telefono varchar(15));


Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.565 sec)

MariaDB [asterisk]> show create table clientes;
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                       |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| clientes | CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
  `telefono` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)


MariaDB [asterisk]> insert into clientes set telefono = '32564787455';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [asterisk]> select * from clientes;
+-------------+
| telefono    |
+-------------+
| 32564787455 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)


MariaDB [asterisk]> DELIMITER &&
MariaDB [asterisk]> create trigger `prefix_phone` BEFORE INSERT ON `clientes`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> SET NEW.telefono = CONCAT('+34',NEW.telefono);
    -> END&&
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.149 sec)

MariaDB [asterisk]> DELIMITER ;

MariaDB [asterisk]> insert into clientes set telefono = '00564787455';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.024 sec)

MariaDB [asterisk]> select * from clientes;
+----------------+
| telefono       |
+----------------+
| 32564787455    |
| +3400564787455 |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)


The delimiter on the END AFAIK this is not a problem/mistake/error.. maybe this a problem in some definite MariaDB version?

@Akina by mistake I mean |  needs to be after the END not ;. If  I execute the op code it does not throw an error until I entered | after DELIMITER ;. In that case it gave ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
